# Wiremock tests always getting a 404 on a simple request

Tags: testing, junit, wiremock

I'm trying to get wiremock to return a 200 status with a simple request in my unit tests however, this unit test is always returning a 404 error.

How can this be solved?

```
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit.WireMockRule;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class WiremockTest {

@Rule
public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(8089); // No-args constructor defaults to port 8080

@Test
public void exampleTest() throws Exception {
    stubFor(get(urlPathMatching("/my/resource[0-9]+"))
            .willReturn(aResponse()
                    .withStatus(200)
                    .withHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml")
                    .withBody("<response>Some content</response>")));

    int result = sendGet("http://localhost/my/resource/121");
    assertTrue(200 == result);

    //verify(getRequestedFor(urlMatching("/my/resource/[a-z0-9]+")));
}

private int sendGet(String url) throws Exception {
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    return responseCode;

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your provided code, I first had to handle the *java.net.ConnectionException* that was being thrown.  Your test's url needs the port on localhost.
`sendGet("http://localhost:8089/my/resource/121")`

After that, I think that the reason you're getting a 404 is that your regex does not match your test url.

> `urlPathMatching("/my/resource[0-9]+")`
>
> should be
>
> `urlPathMatching("/my/resource/[0-9]+")`
>
> note the additional path separator between 'resource' and '[0-9]+'

Online tools for regex testing like [regex101](https://regex101.com/) can be used to test out pattern matching behaviors.  (Remember to escape your forward slashes)

Pattern :`\/my\/resource\/[0-9]+`

Test String: `http://localhost:8089/my/resource/121`

Hope that helps!

Comment: When i set the port to 8089, it works well. However for the bigger picture, i have an embedded Tomcat Server running during my unit tests. And when i give the wiremock rule the same port as the tomcat server, then I will get a binding error since the port is already in use by the tomcat server. Is there a way to get this working for requests going into the tomcat port?

Comment: With the default Wiremock Rule I do not think that what you're asking can be done in Junit context.  There may be other options available, but I'm not really familiar with that context.  My best suggestion would be to go through the wiremock documentation and see if anything there can fit your use case.  http://wiremock.org/getting-started.html